# How can I use Scalas runtime reflection to inspect a passed anonymous function?

Tags: scala, reflection, anonymous-function, mirror, scala-2.11

Assuming I have a method like the following:

```
def getInfo(func: () => T) = {
  //Code goes here.
}
```

How could I use the runtime reflection of Scala 2.11.1 to inspect the passed anonymous function `func`?

I'm especially interested in getting an AST (abstract syntax tree) of `func` and, if possible, the location (line number, file) where the method was first defined. 
All I have accomplished so far is to get information about the type of parameter `func`, not the function itself.

I am aware of the fact that there have been similar questions on SO, but they mainly target other Scala versions.

Comment: A function can't do it, because the AST only exists at compile-time. `getInfo` will have to be a macro.

Comment: So it would theoretically be possible to construct a macro which fetches the information at compile time and adds it to the function as some sort of tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ben mentioned in the comments, this can be done using Scala macros at compile time.

A possible option is to expand the original call to a macro, which queries the necessary information, and then call a internal getInfoMethod, which does something with the information.

Example for `getInfo` function:

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
//getInfo method which gets expanded to macro
def getInfo(func: => Any):Unit = macro FindFreeVars.findMacro

def getInfoInternal(info: Any) {
   //Do something with the collected information
}
```

Example for macro:

```
//Macro delclaration
def getInfoMacro(c: Context)(func: c.Tree): c.Expr[Unit] = {
    import c.universe._

    //Extract information, like enclosingPosition or symols from the function tree. 
    val functionInfo = getFunctionInfo(func)

    //Call internal method
    c.Expr[List[(String, Any)]](q"getInfoInternal($func, $closedVars)")
}
```

More on [Symbols, Trees and Types](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/symbols-trees-types.html) for analysis.

[More complete example](https://github.com/emiswelt/ScalaMacros) of a macro which finds all variables bound from another scope in a function by applying the same technique.